# Dropdown nav only shows if the whole parent element expands with it

Tags: html, css, dropdown, nav

I have this blog in which I recently added my own navbar because blogger's nav doesn't let you add dropdowns. The problem is I wanted the dropdown to show **above** the content below, and not the whole div to expand to fit it in. I even tried a bootstrap navbar but the dropdowns didn't show at all.
Here's the link to my blog: https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 15px 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.syntages:hover .drop-menu-item,
.syntages:active .drop-menu-item {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.fysi:hover .drop-menu-item,
.fysi:active .drop-menu-item {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item {
  color: #25302f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  color: black;
}

button.menu-item {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0 5px;
}

.drop-menu-item {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 430ms;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 430ms;
  transition: opacity 430ms;
}

.drop-menu-table {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}


/*@media screen and (min-width:599px){
            .navbar{height:40px;}
        }
    @media screen and (max-width:598px){
            .navbar{height:99px;}*/
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="main-item"><a class="menu-item" href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/">Αρχική</a></div>
  <div class="main-item"><a class="menu-item" href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%A0%CE%BD%CE%B5%CF%85%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AE%20%CE%96%CF%89%CE%AE">Πνευματική Ζωή</a></div>
  <div class="main-item"><a class="menu-item" href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%A5%CE%B3%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%B1">Υγεία</a></div>
  <div class="main-item syntages"><button class="menu-item">
    Οικογενειακές Συνταγές</button>
    <table class="drop-menu-table">
      <tr>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%93%CE%BB%CF%85%CE%BA%CE%AC%20%CF%87%CF%89%CF%81%CE%AF%CF%82%20%CE%B6%CE%AC%CF%87%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%B7">Γλυκά</a></td>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%9D%CE%B7%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AF%CF%83%CE%B9%CE%BC%CE%B1%20-%20vegan">Νηστίσιμα / Vegan</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%A3%CF%85%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%B4%CE%B5%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC">Συνοδευτικά</a></td>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%91%CE%BB%CE%AC%CE%B4%CF%89%CF%84%CE%B1">Αλάδωτα</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%A3%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%AC%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%82">Σαλάτες</a></td>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%9C%CE%B5%20%CF%88%CE%AC%CF%81%CE%B9">Με ψάρι</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%96%CF%8D%CE%BC%CE%B5%CF%82%20-%20%CF%88%CF%89%CE%BC%CE%B9%CE%AC">Ζύμες / Ψωμιά</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%A3%CF%85%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1%CE%B3%CE%AD%CF%82">Όλες οι Συνταγές</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="main-item fysi"><button class="menu-item">Εικόνες από τη Φύση</button>
    <table class="drop-menu-table">
      <tr>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%A4%CE%B1%CE%BE%CE%AF%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1">Ταξίδια</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%A6%CF%85%CF%84%CE%AC">Φυτά</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%96%CF%8E%CE%B1">Ζώα</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="drop-menu-item"><a href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/search/label/%CE%A6%CF%8D%CF%83%CE%B7">Όλα</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="main-item"><a class="menu-item" href="https://bodyn-soul.blogspot.com/p/blog-page.html">Επικοινωνία</a></div>
</div>
```

The code that I've commented out made the dropdown open individually, as desired, at codeply but, on the contrary, it makes it fall behind content at my blog.
Any suggestions appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than a link to your site which will undoubtedly change making this question useless to others in the future.

Comment: Nevermind, found it. There was an "overflow:hidden;" style applied to the container of the nav by Blogger.